# The tokens were transferred to another wallet, while my wallet received a transfer of 0 tokens

Tags: transfer

The function used is Function: transfer(address recipient,uint256 amount)

And my wallet seems to be correct, but the funds were received by another wallet. Is this a contract issue ?

The tx id is
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x5b335e9e3cc9ed09a1d9a63fa719424b6d9303b262dc59c6aaee672fdda25569

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked your tx and smart contract source code and I think this is a scam contract.
In the transfer function, it take some "marketingFee" if caller or receiver is not owner of smart contract. And the marketing Fee is 100%.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your token sends all tokens to `marketingWallet`

[image]

[image]